# How to write dataframe to csv with a single row header(5k columns)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a pandas dataframe with [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)  so it can be processed by another tool before using it again with python. It is a token dataset with 5k columns. When exported the header is split in two rows. This might not be an issue for pandas but in this case I need to export it on a single row csv. Is this a pandas limitation or a csv format one?

Currently, searching returned no compatible results. The only solution I came up is writing the column names and the values separately, eg. writing an *str*  column list first and then a numpy array to the csv. Can this be implemented, and if so how?

Comment: How do you know it's split into 2 rows? Is this just your viewer or it's really on 2 rows?

Comment: Beware, in a csv file, a row can span multiple lines. Is the header just split on multiple lines of really on multiple rows?

Comment: @EdChum how can I verify that it is not just my viewer? It populates two different cells when opened with excel.

Comment: Well when you read the csv back into pandas, is the number of columns the same? If so, then it's something to do with excel

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem was caused by having multiple indexes. The easiest way to resolve this issue is to specify your own headers. I found reference to an option called `tupleize_cols` but it doesn't exist in current (1.2.2) pandas.

I was using the following aggregation:

```
df.groupby(["device"]).agg({
    "outage_length":["count","sum"],
}).to_csv("example.csv")
```

This resulted in the following csv output:

```
,outage_length,outage_length
,count,sum
device,,
device0001,3,679.0
device0002,1,113.0
device0003,2,400.0
device0004,1,112.0
```

I specified my own headers in the call to `to_csv`; excluding my `group_by`, as follows:

```
}).to_csv("example.csv",header=("flaps","downtime"))
```

And got the following csv output, which was much more pleasing to spreadsheet software:

```
device,flaps,downtime
device0001,3,679.0
device0002,1,113.0
device0003,2,400.0
device0004,1,112.0
```